# Issue uploading PNG images with transparency?

Tags: php, image, transparency, crop, imagecreatefrompng

I'm having some issues uploading PNG images with transparency.

I upload, crop and insert the images in the DB and when I try to show them in the website they come up black. It's only happening with PNG images, for JPG, JPEG and GIF it's working perfect.

Can somebody help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LnY8.jpg)

This is my code:

public function create_square_image($original_file, $destination_file=NULL, $square_size = 100){

```
    // get width and height of original image
    $imagedata = getimagesize($original_file);
    $original_width = $imagedata[0];    
    $original_height = $imagedata[1];

    if($original_width > $original_height){
        $new_height = $square_size;
        $new_width = $new_height*($original_width/$original_height);
    }
    if($original_height > $original_width){
        $new_width = $square_size;
        $new_height = $new_width*($original_height/$original_width);
    }
    if($original_height == $original_width){
        $new_width = $square_size;
        $new_height = $square_size;
    }

    $new_width = round($new_width);
    $new_height = round($new_height);

    // load the image
    if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".jpg") or substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".jpeg")){
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file);
    }
    if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".gif")){
        $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($original_file);
    }
    if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".png")){


                    $original_image = imagecreatefrompng($original_file);       
    }

    $smaller_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $square_image = imagecreatetruecolor($square_size, $square_size);

    imagecopyresampled($smaller_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);

    if($new_width>$new_height){
        $difference = $new_width-$new_height;
        $half_difference =  round($difference/2);
        imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0-$half_difference+1, 0, 0, 0, $square_size+$difference, $square_size, $new_width, $new_height);
    }
    if($new_height>$new_width){
        $difference = $new_height-$new_width;
        $half_difference =  round($difference/2);
        imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0, 0-$half_difference+1, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size+$difference, $new_width, $new_height);
    }
    if($new_height == $new_width){
        imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size, $new_width, $new_height);
    }


    // if no destination file was given then display a png      
    if(!$destination_file){
        imagepng($square_image,NULL,9);
    }

    // save the smaller image FILE if destination file given
    if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".jpg")){
        imagejpeg($square_image,$destination_file,100);
    }
    if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".gif")){
        imagegif($square_image,$destination_file);
    }
    if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".png")){
        imagepng($square_image,$destination_file,9);
    }

    imagedestroy($original_image);
    imagedestroy($smaller_image);
    imagedestroy($square_image);

}
```

Comment: Are the images completely black or just the parts that are supposed to be transparent are black?

Comment: The are images completely black, but it's just happening with PNG images, it's fine when I'm uploading JPEG & JPG images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`imagesavealpha()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) in order to preserve the alpha channel when saving.